# Dynamic background color for span tag

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

I'm trying to add dynamic background coloring for a span tag in my Angular view which contains document types. The following source code is given:

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let record of records">
  <span class="doc-id">
    Document ID: {{ record.id }}
  </span>
  <span>
    {{ record.documentType }}
  </span>
</mat-card>
```

The `record.documentType` can be anything (string only), it comes from the backend. The goal is to add dynamic background coloring for the same document types.

**So for example:**

If the documentType is 'employee', then all employee types should be a random color (let's say green). If it's 'salary', then all salary types should be a different random color (let's say yellow).

I've tried to use different solutions found on Google, but none of them was good enough.

I'm thinking to pass the documentType value to a typescript function, which will generate a new random color if it's not generated one already for that type.

`[ngStyle]="generateRandomBackgroundColor(record.documentType)`

Do you have any suggestions, best practices for this type of issue? I'm using sass in the project, so if there's a sass related suggestion I'm happy to read that as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'randomColor',
})
export class RandomColorPipe implements PipeTransform {
  private static readonly colors: Map<string, string> = new Map();

  /**
   * Generates random hex color
   * https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/random-hex-color/
   */
  private getRandomColor(): string {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  }

  public transform(id: string): string {
    const color = RandomColorPipe.colors.get(id) ?? this.getRandomColor();

    if (!RandomColorPipe.colors.has(id)) {
      RandomColorPipe.colors.set(id, color);
    }

    return color;
  }
}
```

```html
<mat-card *ngFor="let record of records">
  <span class="doc-id">
    Document ID: {{ record.id }}
  </span>
  <span [style.backgroundColor]="'#' + (record.documentType | randomColor)">
    {{ record.documentType }}
  </span>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: This works pretty well, thank you.

However, the color of the text sometimes has not enough contrast, so it's not readable hence it's not accessible. Do you have any idea how to solve that issue?

Comment: @elyndel https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sqsyqn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: you sir are amazing. Works like a charm. :)